# Testing someones sms text address

Tags: php, email, sms

I have an application where I am asking our inspectors to enter their cell number and cell provider so we can send info to them daily.

For those that do not know their service I have created a test feature that sends text messages to about 50 possible addresses with each notifing which service they have

```
$cell_number2 = $_SESSION["u_cell_phone_a"];
$cell_number2 .= $_SESSION["u_cell_phone_p"];
$cell_number2 .= $_SESSION["u_cell_phone_e"];
$to_test = $cell_number2;
//headsers///
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: myaddress@eznmsi.com'. "\r\n";

$subject2 = "Texting Test";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set the users cell phone sms carrier variables //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$t_3riv = $cell_number2 ."@sms.3rivers.net"; // 3 river wireless
$t_acs = $cell_number2 . "@paging.acswireless.com"; // acs wireless
$t_att = $cell_number2 . "@txt.att.net"; // at&t
$t_bellM = $cell_number2 . "@txt.bellmobility.ca"; // bell mobility
$t_bluefrog = $cell_number2 . "@blueskyfrog.com"; // blue sky frog
$t_boost = $cell_number2 . "@myboostmobile.com"; //boost
```

etc....

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// send test text to list of phone sms carriers //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

mail($t_3riv, $subject2, "Your service is, 3 Rivers Wireless",$headers);
mail($t_acs, $subject2, "Your service is, ACS Wireless",$headers);
mail($t_att, $subject2, "Your service is, Att",$headers);
mail($t_bellm, $subject2, "Your service is, Bell Mobility",$headers);
mail($t_bluefrog, $subject2, "Your service is, Blue Sky Frog",$headers);
mail($t_boost, $subject2, "Your service is, Boost",$headers);
```

etc....

this may cause us to get flagged for spam. Which is actually just testing to find the proper text address for our system.

Is there any better way of testing someones text address without sending out and getting some returns.

I am evolving to pear mail smtp to help with persistent smtp connection.

Comment: use a sms gateway, don't rely on  a carrier's email->sms gateway.

Answer (score 1):

What @Dagon said, email to text services are unreliable at best.

That said, have the user enter their carrier information along with their phone number so that you don't have to do kludgy testing like this.

Back in the day you used to be able to download NPA/NXX lists that would help you connect phone number with the carriers that owned them, but now with all this jazz where you can take your number with you when you change carriers that's gone out the window and I have no idea how to reliably deliver SMS messages other than an SMS gateway.

Comment: I have a listing of cell carriers for them to choose from..I am just trying to accommodate all of the users..would you think that most people would know their carrier right? The list of gateways I am using are as follows... http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

Comment: @user2130146 not really the issue, its just a bad approach to use the carriers gateway, they are very unreliable - if you care that a sms  avarices accept that you have to use an external provider. Also that list is 6 years old i see several outdated addresses in it

Comment: is it possible to have the user send a text to a number or an address and then capture the return sms address?

Comment: thank u dragon for pointing out the ancient list I was using...I acquired a new updated list...

Comment: @user2130146 we're talking about something like http://smsgateway.ca/ where you don't have to worry about stuff like that.